# Windows XP - monitor process & relaunch process if it crashes

Tags: windows, process, monitoring, opera, touchscreen

This is my first windows question so apologies if this is obvious or badly worded.

I have a touch screen station that runs Opera in Kisokmode (http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/) which is great and works perfectly.

I want to be able to monitor the Opera process and relaunch it if it crashes or is closed.

Can anyone give me some direction on how this can be done, or is there any out-of-the-box software that can do this for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some software to monitor processes and restart them if they are killed:
http://www.knas.se/Applications/Restarter.aspx 
http://drinkprog.com/kiwi/ 
Just one of the ways to implement such software would be:
1. Open a handle of the target process that needs to be monitored, using `OpenProcess` API with `SYNCHRONIZE` access right.
2. Wait infinitely on that handle using `WaitForSingleObject` or `WaitForMultipleObjects` APIs.
3. If the process exits or gets killed, then wait would be signaled (with return code WAIT_ABANDONED or WAIT_OBJECT_0).
4. Close the handle. Restart process and repeat the above steps.

Comment: +1 Thanks Swatkat. Those programs are great, but both crash when trying to start on Windows XP. By knowledge of coding for Windows machines is nil, so coding something is pretty much out of the question.

Comment: Knas Restarter (first link in above post) worked fine in my system (XP SP3 32bit). Did you get "The application failed to initialize properly" error when you started Knas Restarter? If so, then you need to install .NET framework. You can get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=0a391abd-25c1-4fc0-919f-b21f31ab88b7

Comment: I got that error and installed .Net 4 - I now get "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application"

Comment: Just now found out that .NET 4 is completely new and does not include previous versions of .NET framework. I didn't knew this! Sorry about that. Knas Restarter apparently needs .NET 2.0. You can install .NET 3.5, which includes all previous versions of .NET. You can dowload 3.5 from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d0e5dea7-ac26-4ad7-b68c-fe5076bba986

Comment: By the way, .NET 3.5 and 4 can coexist in a system.

Comment: Ah right. I have used http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/03/04/restart-on-crash/ instead. Restarter would be better but I have run out of time now. Thanks for your help!